# The set $\{g^2 | g \in G\}$ in a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove or disprove that $H =\{g^2 | g \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I tried testing the permutations of $A_4$, however squaring each cycle yielded a cycle in $A_4$ so I'm lacking a counter-example (if there is one). In a nutshell I'm looking for a subgroup such that when you square the permutation cycle, it yields a cycle not in that subgroup.

Or, I could be way off base and figure out that there isn't a counter-example and I need to prove that indeed $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but: you won't be able to show that $H$ is _outside_ of $G$, because groups are closed under multiplication. And inverses won't be the problem, since $(g^2)^{-1} = (g^{-1})^2$. So I think that thinking about whether the product of two squares has to be a square (note that this is true if $G$ is abelian!), as The Chaz says, is the thing to do.

Comment: For extra points, find a group of order $2^k$ for some $k$ in which the set $H$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: I want to prove that normality of H.Let G be a group. Prove or disprove that H={g2|g∈G} is a NORMAL subgroup of G.Can you help me ??

Comment: @gamzekalkan Please do not post new questions as answers. Use the "Ask Question" button to pose questions and/or post *comments* to related questions and answers.

Comment: Great question. Note that this is exercise 54 in chapter 5 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$A_4$ should work. The squares will lie in $A_4$ simply because a group is closed under its multiplication, but there are further obstructions to a subset being a subgroup.

Now, what are the squares in $A_4$? We have two types of non-trivial elements in $A_4$: products of disjoint transpositions such as $[12][34]$, which square to the identity, and $3$-cycles such as $\sigma = [123]$. The $3$-cycles satisfy $\sigma^3 = e$ and hence $\sigma = (\sigma^{-1})^2$, so they are all squares.

So, does the set of all $3$-cycles, together with the identity, form a subgroup of $A_4$? If I've multiplied $[123][423]$ out correctly, then the answer is no. [Another reason, which I think is what Arturo is getting at: there are $8$ different $3$-cycles, and $9$ does not divide $12 = |A_4|$.]

Comment: ... or if you count the number of 3-cycles correctly...

Comment: Yes, but if $g = [123]$ then $g^2 = [132]$, and if $g \in G$ then $g$ does not contain the cycle [423]:

http://tinyurl.com/84x88se

Therefore, I shouldn't be allowed to square any cycle that isn't in $A_4$ I would have thought. Or should I choose my G to be $S_4$?

Comment: @Goober I'm confused. Are you saying that $[423]$ is not a square in $A_4$? All $3$-cycles in $S_4$ are in $A_4$.

Comment: @Dylan [423] is not in $A_4$, therefore I cannot use it as, say $g$ = [423] since $g \in A_4$

Comment: @Goober Why isn't it? $[423] = [43][42]$ can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions. That's what it means to be in $A_4$.

Comment: @Dylan If I square [423] then I get [432]

Comment: @Goober And if you square that?

Comment: @Dylan I get back [423]

Comment: @Goober: So then, $[432]$ is in $A_4$, and it is equal to $g^2$ for some $g$ in $A_4$ (namely, $g=[423]$). What is the problem?

Comment: @Arturo Problem is I need $g^2$ to not be in $A_4$

Comment: @Goober: No, you don't! You are completely misinterpreting the problem. First, it is **impossible** for you to have an element $g$ in a group, and have $g^2$ *not* be in the group: it wouldn't be a group in the first place! Second: the problem is: **given** a group, in this case $A_4$, construct the **set** $\{g^2\mid g\in G\}$. Then verify that this set is not always a subgroup (in the case of $G=A_4$, verify that the set of squares of elements of $A_4$ is not a subgroup of $A_4$). It will fail to be a subgroup because the *set* is not closed under products. But it is always contained in $G$!

Comment: @Goober: In other words: a subgroup must (i) be a subset; (ii) contain the identity; (iii) be closed under products; and (iv) be closed under inverses. You seem to think that the only way this $H$ can fail to be a subgroup is if (i) fails. But (i) never fails (and neither do (ii) and (iv); verify this!). In fact, the *only* way in which $H$ can fail to be a subgroup is if (iii) fails, so in this case you need to verify that (iii) fails.

Comment: @Goober:  Did you not read the answers?  I think it had been pretty well explained to you already that you don't need, and can't get, $g^2$ not to be in $A_4$.

Answer (score 14):

As you suspected, the statement is false. Consider the free group $G$ on two generators, say $x$ and $y$.  Then $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both in $H$, but there is no way to write $x^2 y^2$ as a square. (Remember, $x$ and $y$ don't commute, so $(xy)^2 \not= x^2 y^2$.)

Comment: How do you show $x^2y^2$ is not a square? You showed that $(xy)^2\neq x^2y^2$,i.e., $x^2y^2$ is not a square of $xy$.

Comment: @wxu:  It's not hard to prove.  Why don't you give it a try?  Or if you're not very familiar with free groups, then Dylan's answer is probably more suitable for you.

Comment: @tara,
You are right. It is easy.

Comment: @wxu:  =]  Also, sorry, I assumed you were the person who asked the question, but I see you were not.

Answer (score 5):

May I offer a computational solution?

If you run this code in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), it will give you the number of non-isomorphic groups $G$ of order $n \leq 200$ for which $H$ is not a subgroup.  It encounters thousands of counter-examples in a matter of seconds.

```
for n in [1..200] do
  count:=0;
  for i in [1..NrSmallGroups(n)] do
    G:=SmallGroup(n,i);
    S:=Set(G,g->g^2);
    H:=Group(S);
    if(Size(H)<>Size(S)) then count:=count+1; fi;
  od;
  if(count>0) then Print(n," ",count,"\n"); fi;
od;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of what you would have to do to find a counterexample was confused.

"In a nutshell I'm looking for a subgroup such that when you square the permutation cycle, it yields a cycle not in that subgroup."

What you are trying to do is prove that there exists a group $G$ such that the set $H$ is not a subgroup.  So the counterexample you are looking for is the group $G$, not some subgroup of it.  You correctly guessed that $A_4$ would be an example, but then what you need to show is that the set of all squares of elements of $A_4$ doesn't form a subgroup.  Clearly the problem is *not* going to be that the set of all squares is not even contained in $A_4$, because $A_4$ is a group.  But you can show (as Dylan has mentioned) that there exist two squares in $A_4$ such that their product is not a square.

I'm not sure why I wrote this, since others have already said as much.  I guess I just wasn't quite sure whether you have seen why your approach didn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some very good counterexamples. Here's another idea to consider. An easy exercice has you prove that a group where all elements square to the identity element is commutative. Also, the set $S$ of all squares is "normal"in $G$ in the sense that for all $g$ in $G$, $g^{-1}Sg=S$.

One direction to look at is simple non commutative groups $G$ : the set of all squares is "normal" and strictly larger than $\{1\}$, thus, if it were a subgroup, it would have to be all of $G$.

You can then look at the simple noncommutative group $A_6$ and the even permutation $(12)(3456)$. This is the square of no permutation (even in $S_6$). Thus the set of squares of $A_6$ cannot be a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that if $H$ is a subgroup, then $H$ is also a normal subgroup. Thus a natural way to search for counterexamples is to look at groups with few normal subgroups.

Let $G$ be a finite, nonabelian simple group. Then if $H$ is a subgroup, it must equal $G$, because $g^2 = 1$ for every $g \in G$ implies that $G$ is abelian. If there is an element of order $2$ in $G$, then the map $g \mapsto g^2$ is not injective, thus not surjective, and thus $H$ cannot equal all of $G$.

By Cauchy's theorem, this shows that any finite nonabelian simple group of even order works. So for example, you could pick $G = A_n$ for any $n \geq 5$.

(And by Feit-Thompson, any finite nonabelian simple group works..)

Comment: I just thought I'd say that I like this approach very much...it is very neat!

Answer (score 1):

Still another approach for finite groups: since squaring is a bijection in *odd* ordered groups, the set $H$ of squares equals the whole group $G$ if $\mid G \mid$ = odd. 
It also follows that for groups $G$ of order $2n$, with $n$ odd, the set $H$ is a subgroup indeed. This follows from the fact that in this case the $2$-Sylow subgroup has a normal complement, say $N$ and hence $\mid N \mid$ = $n$ and $|G:N|=2$. Since $N$ consists of squares by the remark in the previous paragraph and all squares must lie in $N$ being of index 2, it follows that $N$ is exactly the set $H$.

Comment: Your answer seems to be saying "yes, the set in question is indeed a subgroup". But this contradicts the other answer(s) which provide counter examples. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: I am only saying that in case the order of $G$ is $2$ times an odd number, the set of squares is in fact a subgroup.